# PHP & MySQL: Get all values from a table?

Tags: php, mysql, unique-values

I'm trying to run this MySQL code in PHP.

```
SELECT DISTINCT teamid FROM teammembers INNER JOIN teams WHERE teams.id = teammembers.teamid
```

If I run this code in SQL, I get around 20 different values, and I would like to save this unique values in an array so I can use them later.

So I'm using this PHP code:

```
$totalteams = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT teamid FROM teammembers INNER JOIN teams WHERE teams.id = teammembers.teamid");
```

Now I want to check if the code is working or not, so I did:

```
echo $totalteams;
```

And as result I got:

```
Resource id #5
```

I also tried with:

```
echo mysql_result($totalteams,0);
```

And it does work that way, but that count asks me for the row number, therefore it only displays one value, and I need all of them.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. you should look at using mysqli, mysql is obsolete in the latest php (5.5)
2. you should really look on google, I'm sure this was answered at least a million times,
3. try something like,

---

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $totalteams )) {   
    print_r( $row );  
}
```

---

Comment: Why did someone downvote? This is the correct answer. It's worth noting that if the OP wanted to echo individual values from the associative array, they should use **echo $row['column_name'];**

Comment: Thanks Joe T and Joel Murphy, both ways are working. Also, I do use mysqli, is there something wrong in the example code I posted where I'm not using it? Finally, I did search in Google but couldn't fine the right answer.

Comment: Hi user2077474, to use mysqli you need to replace any function that starts "mysql_" such as "mysql_query" with the mysqli equivalent ie "mysqli_query" http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php